# In Android Studio, I want to run YouTube when an image is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a code in Android Studio to run YouTube when an image is clicked. However, the value of the intent is coming out null. Does anyone know the reason why?

```kotlin
todoTitleBiding.iconUtube.setOnClickListener {
    intent = this.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube")
    if(intent != null){
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"install YouTube",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iconUtube.setOnClickListener {
val youtubeAppIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID_HERE"))

if (youtubeAppIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(youtubeAppIntent)
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Install YouTube", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

}